# How to make odd/even cols in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, grid, bootstrap-4

I have a section which must contains an image on the left and a text on the right, and in the next col, I have the opposite, I mean, a text on the left and an image on the right. This is my html:

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-desc">
                        <p>text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-desc">
                        <p>text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-desc">
                        <p>text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-desc">
                        <p>text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

On desktop, it looks as it should, but on mobile, the order should be always an image first and then the text.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use flexbox order utility classes for this. [Flexbox Order Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order)

Open the snippet in full screen mode.

Add `order-2 order-md-1` to the text and `order-1 order-md-2` to image.
Also, for this to work, I had to wrap the text and image with a div with class `row`

`order-2 order-md-1` means that on from smallest devices, make the order of the item **2** and on medium and after that, make order **1**

**Update**: You can add `align-items-center` to row to vertically center items

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="feature-desc">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
        <div class="feature-desc">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="feature-desc">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
        <div class="feature-desc">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Amazing! Actually, I'm a designer but I get some front-end freelance jobs and I'm still migrating my knowledge from bootstrap 3. Hope you can help with 1 more question: why isn't it necessary to add the ".d-flex" class in order to make that order work? If I wanna align those texts vertically, it should have the d-flex class on their divs?

Comment: @joaogdesigner, because row in bootstrap 4 is display:flex, so there is no need to add d-flex

Comment: Great! I just figured it out on the link you mentioned about Bootstrap Flex. It worked, thank you! Bootstrap 4 is really a magic.

Comment: @joaogdesigner I helped u so much, please accept my answer